# Final Fantasy RPG

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created [final-fantasy-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-rpg) for a question about Return Games’ FFRPG. As far as I can tell, though, Returner Games is quite defunct, and in any event there has never been an official *Final Fantasy* RPG. There are definitely other fan-made *Final Fantasy* RPGs, though. There’s the SEED one, Dust’s d6-based one, and so on.

As far as I can tell, we don’t have any questions about any of these systems. That said, if we ever get any, having [final-fantasy-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-rpg) refer specifically to Returner Games’ version may be problematic and also quite possibly unfair – I see no particular reason why they would get to lay exclusive claim to that title.

So, does anyone think it should be changed to something else? [returner-games-ffrpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/returner-games-ffrpg) is pretty long, for example.

Comment: I don't think it matters at all.

Comment: Related: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/tags-for-rpgs-that-have-name-conflicts

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Heh, I had not forgotten it (though probably should have linked it myself), but I wasn't sure if the fact that it's not official/theoretically Squeenix might make their own some day had anything to do with it. ...which, I didn't really add to my question so I'm not sure how I expected anyone to answer it.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you'd forgotten it or not, but it's nice to have the other question show up in the Linked sidebar anyway! It makes navigating the increasingly-tangled history of policy discussions marginally easier to figure out for new users.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there even used to be a [final-fantasy-rgp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-rgp) tag specifically for the Returner Games version, and it was made for that question you (re-)tagged with it earlier today.

We generally tag with the name of a game. When there is a name collision where multiple unrleated games share the same name, we resolve that in whatever way makes most sense for the particular games. However, we don't bother unless we actually have questions that *need* those other tags, so until one of the other claimants to the FFRPG title appears on the site, Returner Games version's claim to the name is uncontested and it gets the tag.